# Trouble with adding an update field which records time of update in database

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am using SQL server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition.

I have a database with a table "user". Now I need to add a field in the table which records time of update when the record is updated from front end an ASP.NET website.

I have added a field in the table called "dtUpdateFlag" with properties as follows:

[Properties](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wps7f48d0whlhrz/dtUpdateFlag.png)

I have than modified the current stored update procedure to include a line to update the filed to current UTC time. The procedure after change goes as follows:

```
USE [Removed]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[tblUserUpdate]    Script Date: 12/05/2013 11:38:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tblUserUpdate] (
    @intUserId int,
    etc, etc 
    @blnDummyUser bit
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

if(@intCityId =0)
Begin
set @intCityId = NULL
End

UPDATE
    [tblUser]
SET
    [strFirstName] = @strFirstName,
    etc, etc
        [dtUpdateFlag]= GETUTCDATE()
    WHERE
     [intUserId] = @intUserId

GO
```

However, when I look at the result of the query the dtUpdateFlag field continues to be shown as Null.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure the @intUserId is assigned with correct value? are the other fields getting updated?? Also, try to make the column non-nullable, that way you will know if the row is being updated or not..

Comment: Hello there, Other fields are getting updated fine and inuserid field is correct as every thing else works.

Comment: Are there any other updates/inserts in the procedure? Are we positive we're looking at the right query?

Comment: hi, barthazar Yes there  are other updates and these are working fine. Only the date time column is not being updated in this case.